# style nav-pills in navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am not sure if correct but using bootstrap nav-pills in a navbar does not work as the nav takes priority in the bootstrap.css. If correct then are we not suppose to use these nav styles in the navbar ?

Line 4094 `.nav-pills > .active > a, .nav-pills > .active > a:hover, .nav-pills > .active > a:focus { color: #ffffff; background-color: #0088cc; }`

line 4623

```
 .navbar .nav > .active > a,
    .navbar .nav > .active > a:hover,
    .navbar .nav > .active > a:focus {
      color: #555555;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: #e5e5e5;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
         -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
              box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use it in following way :
Jsfiddle [with navbar and navpills](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/DJtsa/)

```
 .navbar .nav-pills >li >a {
    color: #005580;
 }
   .navbar .nav-pills > li > a:hover {
      background-color: #0088cc;
 }
 .navbar .nav-pills .active > a {
    background-color:#ccc;
    color:#0088cc;
}

<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse" class="btn btn-navbar">
  <i class="icon-bar"></i>
  </a>

    <a class="brand" href="">New Icon Menu</a>

    <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
            <li><a href=""><i class="icon-home icon-2x"></i> Home<br></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href=""><i class=" icon-pencil icon-2x"></i>About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href=""><i class=" icon-briefcase icon-2x"></i>Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href=""><i class=" icon-envelope icon-2x"></i>Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have edit the above as it the background-color: on the active link where the nav still take priority. Are we just not supposed to use this in the navbar ?

Comment: This is the way to create navbar with navpills . And I have included the responsive part into it . So its good to use it the way I suggested . But you can customize it the way you want .

Comment: have copied your html and still see the same. line .navbar nav > .active still has priority when it comes to the background color. how do i supply my html for you to see ?

Comment: You want to set the background color of navbar ?

Comment: nope, the background color of the active nav. For the nav-pills it should be blue but the Nav background takes priority in the css and shows as grey. So I am guessing that nav-pills was not meant to be used in the Navbar element. On Bootstrap site the nav styles are not in a navbar as examples

Comment: @user1614384 will ya select this as answer , will highly appreciate .

Comment: thanks, i have added the CSS. I still think bootstrap is wrongly configured as these should work as default in the code. thanks anyway

Comment: Great it worked for you .... if you can select this answer ,, it will boost my confidence to help more people . Thanks

Comment: sure ... where do i select it as no option for me to select